# Reference to Harnack's proof of Harnack's inequality in real algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, real-algebraic-geometry

Harnack's Theorem in real algebraic geometry states the following: If $X$ is a nonsingular projective curve of genus $g$ defined over $\mathbb{R}$ then the number of connected components of $X(\mathbb{R})$ is $\leq g+1$.

Harnack proved this using Bezout's theorem. I would like a reference to Harnack's proof of Harnack's theorem. (I am not interested in Klein's proof or any of the other proofs of this theorem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Harnack's inequality is proved with Harnack's original proof in the book "Real algebraic geometry" by Bochnak, Coste and Roy.

Comment: @user443117 : by the way this is not really a reference but if you are interested about the subject, the website of Oleg Viro contains lot of interesting constructions/theorems about topology of real algebraic curves !